# If a distribution function gives me values greater than 1 does it mean that my equation is wrong?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If the equation I have that represents a distribution function, gives me values greater than 1, does that mean that my equation is wrong?

Or can I just divide the function by its highest value? (I think this is called normalisation but I am uncertain of that).

Comment: Not only do you need values limited by 1, you also need total area (or sum) to be 1. Normalization by highest value won't always do that.

Comment: @Randall I am confused. A probability density can take values greater than $1$, no ? Or are we talking about discrete random variables here?

Comment: I was thinking discrete.  Maybe OP can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "distribution function".

A PDF (say $f$) can assume arbitrarily large values. But a CDF (say $F$) must satisfy $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} F(x) = 1$.

(For example, the function which takes the value $100$ on the interval $[0,0.01]$ and $0$ everywhere else is the PDF of a uniform distribution.)

If you have a candidate $F$ for a CDF, then you can ensure this by normalizing as you suggest: $G(x)= F(x)/\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}F(t)$ will be a CDF. If $F$ is already a CDF, then the denominator is $1$ and $G=F$.

If you have a candidate $f$ for a PDF, then you again can normalize it: $f(x)/\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\;dt$ will be a PDF, with corresponding CDF given by $F(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^xf(t)\;dt/\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\;dt$.

This assumes everything involved is finite, the functions aren't negative, etc etc.

Comment: The function I have is based on an integral as: $\int^x_{-\infty}$, so it means it is a PDF and hence can have values higher than 1?

Comment: Most often "density" means PDF and "distribution" means CDF, but you should really say which you mean. Being written as an integral means nothing, anything can be written that way. Why not be specific and say what the function is, and say whether you mean PDF or CDF?

Comment: I am not entirely certain, let me try and find it

Comment: "It is difficult to answer if one does not understand the question." -- Sarek

Comment: It is the "phase-space density distribution function" https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0101524.

Comment: But it is not clear as to if it is PDF or CDF

Comment: My guess is neither. See [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_function_(physics)). This may be physics terminology and not probability.